# what should be the hash function for ip addresses?

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in this course of data structures so i have no idea of representing ip addresses as key to the hash tables.Kindly guide me how can i implement hashtables having ip addresses as key and path or different ip address as value?

Comment: What did you tried till now? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since IPv4 have 32-bit addresses, you don't need a hash function, you can use the IP address as is.

For IPv6, XOR folding the 128 bits to 32 or 64 is probably good enough.

If you implement the hash table yourself, don't forget to randomize the hash before reducing to indexes.